# Do we really have to OOPsify everything in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have joined a new company and here they have created classes for just about everything, even for the unrelated utility functions.

Consider this:

```
export default class Utils {
static method1()
static method2()
static method3()
}
```

vs

```
export const method1 = () => {}
export const method2 = () => {}
export const method3 = () => {}
```

Is there any specific advantage one gets by encapsulating the independent methods inside a class? Which is the recommended way for a scalable code base?

Comment: Sounds like whoever's implementing those rules is confusing other OO-languages with Javascript, IMO, a "class" composed of unrelated static methods doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I share your opinion. JS/TS has better constructs for functional programming so why not use those instead of encapsulating everything just for the sake of it.

Comment: Encapsulating everything (or, many things) for the sake of it isn't a bad idea https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/388052/rationale-to-prefer-local-variables-over-instance-variables https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361517/does-it-make-sense-to-create-blocks-just-to-reduce-a-variables-scope but the problem here is that exporting a class doesn't help that, in comparison to having named exports (in fact, a class is arguably worse, since it's mutable)

Comment: @CertainPerformance good point about named exports—it would certainly seem more advantageous to be able to individually import individual utility functions as required.

Comment: In your example you group three methods together , instead of having three loose methods floating around without context. So yes it makes sense to add a class. Now we know these methods are Util methods, and we have an easy way to use them: just type `Util.` in your code editor and you will get a neat list. Don’t be so afraid of the class keyword. It’s just a function with a fancy name!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common misconception about Typescript. Typescript does not mean you have to use classes. Typescript is Javascript with types. Write your code as you would in Javascript, add types where necessary, and you should be fine.

If you want to take advantage of classes (an ES2015 feature not necessarily a Typescript feature) Typescript will help you have strong types for the classes. But you don't need classes to write good Typescript.

The reasons this misconception probably appeared is that the early demos always showed classes as they were still not in most browsers and needed down-compilation and everyone wanted them. This lead people to the false impression that Typescript works best with classes. But this is definitely not so.

In your particular case I would actually argue it is a bad use of classes. Static classes are an invention for languages that do not allow functions to live anywhere else but in a class. In Javascript the module can encapsulate such static methods as well as any class and is a more Javascript oriented way to do things.